# How to access the Push Notification counter on Android (TV)?

Tags: android-notifications, android-tv, android-notification-bar, android-push-notification

I would like to access the number of currently available push notifications The following :[image: example has '1' push notification], here on a Android TV emulator image..

So how can I **read** that number?

EDIT: I do not want to set anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NotificationListenerService` to manage everything related to notifications. You can also extend it and override methods like `onNotificationPosted` to maintain your own counter. Or better yet, directly use `getActiveNotifications()`.

Check the docs here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService#getActiveNotifications()

You need to give your app permission to access notifications for this to work.

Comment: Which exact permission? getActiveNotifications was always 0 in my tests

Comment: Please check this example https://github.com/Chagall/notification-listener-service-example

Comment: After you install the app ensure that permission is actually granted by going into app's settings -> permissions

Comment: If getActiveNotifications is still not working maybe you can try to intercept notifications and maintain the counter yourself.

Comment: Before calling [getActiveNotifications](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService#getActiveNotifications()) make sure [onListenerConnected](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService#onListenerConnected()) is called.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a Custom notification count.

By default, each notification increments a number displayed on the long-press menu (visible in figure 1), but you can override this number for your app.

For example, this might be useful if you're using just one notification to represent multiple new messages but you want the count here to represent the number of total new messages.

To set a custom number, call `setNumber()` on the notification - in here below

```
public NotificationCompat.Builder setNumber(int number)
```

Sets the number of items this notification represents. On the latest platforms, this may be displayed as a badge count for Launchers that support badging. Prior to `Build.VERSION_CODES.O` it could be shown in the header. And prior to `Build.VERSION_CODES.N` this was shown in the notification on the right side.

Please Refer this article
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges